# CSS Background Image Transition

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, transition

I am trying to make a bg gradient fade in when the class on the container is changed. The code works fine in IE 10 but not Chrome or Firefox, which is very unusual, IE is usually the pain!

I have 3 classes declared, jquery swaps the classes when a link is clicked. The fade works fine in ie. Here is the css with the classes that are being swapped, along with the jquery:

```
#container.home #content{
    width:100%;
    display:table-row;
    height:100%;

}
#container.home.primary #content{
    background-color:#fbac19;
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left,#79c043  45%,#ffffff 80%);    
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#79c043  45%,#ffffff 80%);    
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left,#79c043  45%,#ffffff 80%);    
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left,#79c043  45%,#ffffff 80%);
    -moz-transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
    -webkit-transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
    -o-transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
    -ms-transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
    transition:background-image 2000ms linear;   
}

#container.home.secondary #content{
    background-color:#50c0ef;
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left,#50c0ef 45%,#ffffff 80%);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#50c0ef 45%,#ffffff 80%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left,#50c0ef 45%,#ffffff 80%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left,#50c0ef 45%,#ffffff 80%);
    -moz-transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
    -webkit-transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
    -o-transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
    -ms-transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
    transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
}

#container.home.colleges #content{
    background-color:#fbac19;
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left,#fbac19 45%,#ffffff 80%);    
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#fbac19 45%,#ffffff 80%);    
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left,#fbac19 45%,#ffffff 80%);    
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left,#fbac19 45%,#ffffff 80%);
    -moz-transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
    -webkit-transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
    -o-transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
    -ms-transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
    transition:background-image 2000ms linear;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //home page search tab click
                $("#container.home ul#search-nav li a").click(function(){
                    // get the rel 
                    var rel = $(this).attr("rel");

                    // remove active class from all links
                    $("#container.home ul#search-nav li a").removeClass("active");

                    // remove classes from body
                    $("#container").removeClass("primary"); 
                    $("#container").removeClass("secondary");
                    $("#container").removeClass("colleges");

                    // add the new class
                    $("#container").addClass(rel);

                    // add active class tolink
                    $(this).addClass("active");

                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `background-image` to just `background`? And it'd be helpful if you provided an example page or your relevant HTML

Comment: Here's a starting point fiddle. Update the HTML and post it in your question. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/BjGHe/1/